# Disabling hardware acceleration for Night Shift

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mojave, night-shift

I'm noticing some artifacts when I watch full-screen videos on macOS with Night Shift enabled, and I suspect they are caused by hardware, because they disappear whenever an overlay appears over a full-screen video.

So, I was wondering, is there any way to disable hardware acceleration for Night Shift? And, if not, then is there any other application I can use that would perform the same function, but without taking advantage of hardware acceleration? (maybe an old version of f.lux or something else?)

Comment: "[The artifacts] disappear whenever an overlay appears over a full-screen video." What does this have to do with Night Shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the artifacts disappear whenever an overlay appears, I solved the issue by creating an app that displays a persistent, invisible overlay:

1. Created a new macOS Cocoa App in Xcode.
2. Edited the window properties in `MainMenu.xib`, in the attributes inspector, and unchecked "Title Bar", "Shadow", "Close", "Minimize" and "Resize", then in the size inspector I set content size width and height to 1, and initial position x and y to 0.
3. Edited `Info.plist` and added a new property "Application is agent (UIElement)" set to `YES`.
4. Edited `AppDelegate.swift` and changed `applicationDidFinishLaunching` to:

```swift
window.isOpaque = false
window.alphaValue = 0
window.ignoresMouseEvents = true
window.level = .floating
window.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .transient]
```

5. Compiled the app for production with Product > Archive > Distribute App > Copy App.

Now, whenever I want to watch full-screen videos with Night Shift turned on, I can start the application and there won't be any further artifacts. I can then close it from Activity Monitor. Another option would be to have it run at startup (System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items).

Comment: The real problem is why you get 'artifacts' in the first place. If it's a hardware problem, then any software solution is just a sticking plaster over a deep wound.

Comment: @benwiggy, that's true. It's definitely a hardware problem, and since the laptop is so old, there's no good hardware solution. This is a hack, but it works and I can use my flawed laptop.